# 'redirect' ssh path?

Tags: debian, ssh

Instead of using...

```
ssh://user@mysite.net:1234/mnt/thing/usr/prj
```

I want to use

```
ssh://user@mysite.net:1234/prj
```

How would I do this? It would be good if users can't access `/home`, `/var` and such. I only need this for data transfers.

Comment: How about a symlink? `ln -s /mnt/thing/usr/prj /prj`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restricting an SCP/SFTP user to a directory](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9853/restricting-an-scp-sftp-user-to-a-directory)

Comment: Concur. Pretty much the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [scponly](http://sublimation.org/scponly/) 'shell' and set up a chroot.

Answer (score 0):

Create a user whose home directory is `/prj`.

Create a `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for the user which contains the remote users public key, as well as some restriction on the commands and ssh options available, like:

```
command="/usr/bin/scp-wrapper",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwar
ding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQA
BAAABAQCblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahbla
hblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahbl
ahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahb
lahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahbla
hblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahB user@site.com
```

Make it as restrictive as possible.

Then you'll need to create that wrapper for scp.  Something as simple as the following will work, but you'll want to add more security conscious checks and tests before using it in production.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

This is just an example of what's possible.  In this case, the full scp command is captured in the environment variable `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`, but since you can't specify a command with arguments in the `command=` clause of the `.authorized_keys` file, you need the wrapper.

Users can probably still access sticky public directories, like /tmp, but they'll have no access to roam around /var, or /home.

and they may be able to pull files off your server, but you could wrap all this up with `chroot`, and secure the system quite a bit more, with minimal effort.