# Simple jail for user with open-ssh

Tags: ubuntu, openssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restricting an SSH/SCP/SFTP user to a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9853/restricting-an-ssh-scp-sftp-user-to-a-directory)

Can I confine my users to their /home/%u directory using simply open-ssh configuration? I did the following from what I found on the Internet
Stopped the server
To the sshd_config file appended the following

```
Match group sftpusers
    ChrootDirectory /home/%u
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

started the server

**FYI I have the users added to sftpusers group**

My users can still access entire file structure on my system

Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS with open-ssh installed

Answer (score 2):

You also need to use `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp`. Forbid all the other forwardings, and `ForceCommand internal-sftp`.

Also, as said in sshd_config man page, the directory to chroot into must be owned by root and not writable by anybody, which probably is not the case for your `/home/%u`.

Probably, you'd want:

```
sudo mkdir -p /jail/home
sudo mount --bind /home /jail/home
```

and have

```
ChrootDirectory /jail
```

Or to restrict users to their own directory, you'd need a bind-mount for each user:

```
cd /home
for u in */ do
  sudo mkdir -p "/jail/$u/home/$u"
  sudo mount --bind "$u" "/jail/$u/home/$u"
done
```

And have

```
ChrootDirectory /jail/%u
```