# Best mechanism for logging in and uploading backup files

Tags: ssh, backup

I have a server that I want to regularly backup. I create backups with encrypted tar using OpenSSL, and now I want to connect to my home server and upload my backed up files there.

I need a mechanism, with which I can connect to my home server, log in, and be able to only upload and read the files there. If my server gets compromised, I don't want the hacker to have access to my home server. So I want the account only to be able to write/read files into **only one** directory, without even being able to peek on the system files in my home folder.

What's the best transfer mechanism to do that? SSH or FTPS or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If the server must login to your home server, you could [restrict SSH access via chroot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9853/restricting-an-ssh-scp-sftp-user-to-a-directory). For your usecase however I'd go the other way around: let your home server *fetch* the backup from the server, so the server doesn't need to login to your home server at all.