# Restrict password-less backup with SFTP

Tags: ssh, sftp, key-authentication, account-restrictions

I need to perform backup of a server to my computer using Duplicity:

```
duplicity /etc sftp://backup@my.dynamic.ip.address//home/backup
```

Before this can be done, I need to allow password-less access by doing the following:

```
$ ssh-keygen
$ ssh-copy-id backup@my.dynamic.ip.address
$ ssh backup@my.dynamic.ip.address
```

My question is, how do I restrict the command to just this SFTP transfer in the public key that is generated?

> `command="restrict to sftp",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAA…`

And since I am on a dynamic IP address, how do I overcome the "missing known host" problem each time my IP changes?

Comment: http://www.snailbook.com/faq/restricted-scp.auto.html

Comment: "missing known host problem": use the StrictHostKeyChecking=no option to ssh

Comment: @Marki, thanks, setting that on ssh_config works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> #### Question #1
>
> My question is, how do I restrict the command to just this SFTP transfer in the public key that is generated?

There are 2 methods for doing this.

#### 1. -- Restricting through sshd

This method involves setting up the SFTP feature within your SSH daemon, `sshd`. This is controlled through the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` configuration file. **NOTE:** This will restrict the user, `backup` to only be allowed to SFTP into the server.

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp

## You want to put only certain users (i.e users who belongs to sftpusers 
## group) in the chroot jail environment. Add the following lines at the end 
## of /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Match User backup
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

#### 2. -- Restricting through authorized_keys

This method doesn't involve any changes to the `sshd_config` file. You can limit a user + a SSH key to a single command via the `command=` feature which you've already mentioned in your question. The trick is in what command you include. You can put the SFTP server in this `command=` line, which has the same effect as setting up the SFTP server in your `sshd_config` file.

```
# User backup's $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys file
command="/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server" ssh-dss AAAAC8ghi9ldw== backup@host
```

**NOTE:** if the user has write access to  `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, they can read and/or modify it. For example, they could download it, edit it, and reupload it stripping away the `commmand=...`, granting him unfettered command access, including the shell. If the user has write access to `~/.ssh`, they could also simply unlink and recreate the file, or `chmod` it to write access. Many possible solutions exist, such as putting the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` files away in a non-user-writable place, such as with:

```
Match Group sftponly
    AuthorizedKeysFile      /etc/ssh/authorized_keys/%u
```

> #### Question #2
>
> And since I am on a dynamic IP address, how do I overcome the "missing known host" problem each time my IP changes?

This is trickier but doable using the `from=` feature within the `authorized_keys` file as well. Here we're limiting access from only the host, `somehost.dyndns.org`.

> from="somehost.dyndns.org",command="/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-dss AAAAC8ghi9ldw== backup@host

The additional settings after the `command=` are equally important, since they'll limit the use of SSH key even further.

*breakdown of features*

- `from='hostname1,hostname2,''` - Restricts access from the specified IP or hostname patterns
- `command='command'` - Runs the specified command after authentication
- `no-pty` - Does not allocate a pty (does not allow interactive login)
- `no-port-forwarding` - Does not allow port forwarding
- `no-X11-forwarding` - user won't be able to remove display X11 GUIs
- `no-agent-forwarding` - user won't be able to forward through this host to other internal hosts

To get rid of the message about the "missing known hosts" you can add this SSH option to the client when it connects like so:

```
$ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ....
```

See the man page, `ssh_config` for full details about this switch.

#### Restricting the user's shell

For both solutions above you'll likely want to lock down the `backup` user by limiting this user's shell in the `/etc/passwd` file as well. Typically you'll want to set it to `scponly`, but there are other choices for this as well. See this U&L Q&A titled: "[Do you need a shell for SCP?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9837/do-you-need-a-shell-for-scp)" for ways of doing this.

The use of `/sbin/nologin` can also be used if you opt to use the chroot feature from `sshd_config` as outlined in **#1** above. However if you opt to use the method outlined in **#2**, then you'll likely have to use `scponly` or something else  for the user's shell in `/etc/passwd`.

---

#### BONUS - Extending #2 above

If you need to expose a set of commands for this user you can also do this. Create a script like so, `/home/backup/commands.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

case $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND in
  "diskspace")
    df -h
    ;;
  "dirlist")
    ls -1
    ;;
  "apache_restart")
    /etc/init.d/apache restart
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Unknown command"
esac
```

You then setup the `authorized_keys` file like so:

```
command="/bin/sh /home/user/commands.sh" ssh-dss AAAAC8ghi9ldw== user@host
```

The `backup` user can then run these commands like so:

```
# diskspace
$ ssh -q user@remote_host diskspace
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/dev-root   39G  2.2G   35G   6% /

# dirlist
$ ssh -q remote_host dirlist
commands.sh
dump.sql
```

#### References

- [SSH Tips and Tricks](http://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2011/05/02/ssh-tips-and-tricks/)
- [Five Minutes to an Even More Secure SSH](http://www.unixlore.net/articles/five-minutes-to-even-more-secure-ssh.html)

Comment: Be careful of what commands you allow the user to access or the user may have the ability to gain a full shell. As an example, if you give someone access to vim they could easily :!/bin/bash   or :!/bin/someotherprogram.

Comment: @rking - yes that goes without saying...

Comment: Thanks for giving me such a detailed answer. The command restriction works perfect. But there are two problems. 1) The dynamic ip refers to my computer, not the server. The hostnames in the "from" field of the authorized_keys file only restrict the address from which the server can access my computer and does nothing to solve the "missing known host" problem on my computer. 2) Disabling shell login for the backup user on my computer with `/sbin/nologin` will prevent the server from accessing my computer with SFTP. This I tried.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The server S becomes the client when it does the backend SFTP connection to my computer C. The "missing known host" problem occurs whenever the server S doing the backup connects to a location not listed on its ssh `known_hosts` file. Marki provided the correct solution in his comment. The `from` parameter in the `authorized_keys` file on my computer C only restricts the location from which S can connect to C.

Comment: Yes, please go ahead to make the edit. By the way I realize that `/sbin/nologin` works if I use force command `internal-sftp` instead of `/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server` which you have specified on the cert. I guess these are two different subsystems. And creating a chroot directory for the former is much more straight forward.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow - yeah that's what I thought, our SFTP server has all the users as nologin, but I took your comment as perhaps something unique to your system. I showed the 2 methods for cases where you might not be able to change `sshd_config`. Yeah the chroot is the cleanest approach.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow - incorporated mods into A, let me know if it looks OK.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. This is really good enough. Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Restricted Shell

You need to assign a restricted shell such [scponly](https://github.com/scponly/scponly/wiki) or [rssh.](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/)

When you use scp or sftp you are connecting to the remote site over ssh and then the remote shell executes a scp proccess or sftp process. What you need is a restricted shell that only allows scp or sftp to lock down the login.