# Restrict user access in linux

Tags: users, account-restrictions

I'm creating a new user with the following details:

```
useradd -d /var/www/html/testuser.com -G users testuser
```

I proceed by creating a new password for the user and attempt to login via SSH, I land on /var/www/html/testuser.com but I can still go back in the directories. I want to restrict user permissions so that they can only manage the content inside the testuser.com and sibblings (so they can do all normal operations), I do not want the user to be able to navigate back in the directories and effectively have root access.

Comment: We need to define more carefully what you want to do -- this user does not have "root(-user) access", forex, they won't be able to write files in `/etc`; and you don't want to deny them access to `/bin` or `/usr/bin`, because they won't have any commands to run. Maybe you're looking for `chroot`?

Comment: I guess! I want them to be able to create/remove directories, upload files via SFTP... it's basically a domain folder and they should be able to manage the files as they want, I'm not really interested in allowing users to run any otehr management commands

Comment: Maybe `setfacl` on the user account?

Answer (score 7):

Users don't “effectively have root access” just because they can browse other directories. All users with shell access can browse the software installation — this isn't confidential information after all, since it can be downloaded from any number of sites. If there are directories that you don't want to expose to all shell users, given them appropriately restrictive permissions.

If you want to have a second layer of safety, you can make the accounts more restricted. If you only want to allow these users to browse, upload and download files under `/var/www/html/testuser.com`, then don't give them a shell account, give them a restricted account that can only use SFTP. You can specify options for a specific account in [`sshd_config`](http://www.openssh.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config) with a `Match` block. (Put this at the end of the file, since the `Match` directive extends to the next `Match` directive or to the end of the file.)

```
Match User testuser
    Force-command internal-sftp
    ChrootDirectory /var/www/html/testuser.com
```

If you want to allow the users to use a few more commands such as scp and rsync, but not general shell access, use [rssh](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/) or [scponly](https://github.com/scponly/scponly/wiki) as the shell on their account, and install and configure rssh or scponly to specify which commands you want to allow (see [Do you need a shell for SCP?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9837/do-you-need-a-shell-for-scp/9839#9839)).

If you want to give a shell account that only allows running a few whitelisted programs, make their shell a [restricted shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_shell). Note that these users will be able to access files outside their home directory, based on file permissions.

If you want to give full shell access, but make everything other than home directories invisible, then you need to create some form of [jail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jail_(computer_security)). The weakest form of jail is a [chroot jail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot), which restricts the user to a branch of the directory tree. Restricting a user to a chroot is as easy of specifying `ChrootDirectory` in `sshd_config`; however, since the user cannot exit the jail, the directory must contain all the programs that the user will use and their data. You can use [bind mounts](https://openvz.org/Bind_mounts) to make some directories (e.g. `/usr`) visible inside the jail.

Comment: This info help me a lot, and prevent me to make another question. Thanks @Gilles!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look in `man 5 sshd_config` at the option `ChrootDirectory`.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the permissions of `/var/www/html` so that only root can view/modify the files/folders.

Like:

```
chown root:root  /var/www/html
```