# SSH via next hop, user has no shell on next hop

Tags: ssh

I have machines A, B and C.

User is on Machine A and wants to ssh to Machine C via Machine B. User has shells on Machine A and C, but /usr/sbin/nologin on Machine B. Is it possible to ssh to Machine C via B?

The following command results in.

```
ssh -t B ssh C
This account is currently not available.
```

If I ssh to Machine C with a user with shell on B, the command works.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184031/can-a-command-be-executed-over-ssh-with-a-nologin-user?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Having read the [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184031/can-a-command-be-executed-over-ssh-with-a-nologin-user?rq=1) from patrix' comment, I can tell that's still possible, if ssh *doesn't try* to execute the shell. A recent feature of [openssh](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/openssh-client/ssh.1.en.html) 7.3 is called `ProxyJump` (and is only a built-in and optimized (using pipes) shortcut for some longer `ProxyCommand`). This feature works only at the tunnel level and never executes the shell on the intermediate host.

So if on B the user account login is disabled by a `nologin` shell, but authentication is still working, and there's no ssh configuration preventing forwarding (ie: `AllowTcpForwarding` is not set to only `remote` or `no`, but to at least `local` or `yes`), the working command is simply:

```
ssh -J B C
```

On older ssh versions and without configuration you could do the same with something like:

```
ssh -f -N -L 2222:C:22 B
ssh -p 2222 localhost
```

The key point is this:

> -N      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just for‐
>           warding ports.