# Make sshd override login shell of a group of users

Tags: ssh, sshd, openssh, restricted-shell

My users are shared across a number of machines via LDAP.

For *one* of those machines (let's call it 'fileserf'), I would like to restrict *some* users in what they can do (actually: prevent them from logging into an interactive session via ssh).
On the *other* machines, these users should be able to use ssh normally.

So my initial idea was to use the `internal-sftp` subsystem, along the lines of:

```
Match group sftponly
     ChrootDirectory %h
     X11Forwarding no
     AllowTcpForwarding no
     ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

This works ok as it restricts only the members of the (local) group `sftponly` on a single host `fileserf`, but unfortunately the `internal-sftp` subsystem *only* allows `sftp` and not `scp` (or `rsync`).

So I did some more research and found `rssh`, which seems to allow me to do exactly what I want to do (permission-wise).

Now the problem is that I cannot set the login-shell of those users to `/usr/bin/rssh` in my LDAP, because that would mean that they would be restricted on *all* machines, not just on `fileserf`.

So my idea is to override the login shell via some configuration in fileserf's `sshd_config`:

```
Match group sftponly
     X11Forwarding no
     AllowTcpForwarding no
     ForceCommand /usr/bin/rssh
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, since now the users get a `Connection closed` whenever they try to `sftp` into the machine:

```
$ ssh user@fileserf 

This account is restricted by rssh.
Allowed commands: scp sftp 

If you believe this is in error, please contact your system administrator.

Connection to fileserf closed.

$ sftp user@fileserf
Connection closed
$
```

How can I make `ForceCommand` work with `rssh`?

Alternatively, How can I configure `sshd` to override the login-shell for a group of users?

Comment: If you can add these users to a local group, perhaps you can create local users which shadow them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`rssh` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/rssh.1.html) indicates it should be the login shell of these users:

```
The  system  administrator  should  install the shell on the restricted
system.  Then the password file entry  of  any  user  for  whom  it  is
desireable  to  provide  restricted  access should be edited, such that
their shell is rssh. For example:

      luser:x:666:666::/home/luser:/usr/bin/rssh
```

With the `ForceCommand`, only that command is run. When you run `scp` or `sftp`, commands are run by SSH (`scp`, `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`, respectively), and of course they can't be run unless the program executed by `ForceCommand` uses `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` to do so. So, for `rssh` to do its job, it has to be the login shell, not a `ForceCommand`.

Related:

- [Do you need a shell for SCP?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9837/70524)

---

You can, instead, use a wrapper script that will use `rssh` instead of the login shell to execute commands. For example:

`/usr/local/bin/wrapper-shell`:

```
#! /bin/sh
rssh -c "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
```

And in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match group sftponly
     X11Forwarding no
     AllowTcpForwarding no
     ForceCommand /usr/local/bin/wrapper-shell
```

With `/usr/local/bin/wrapper-shell` being executable should work.

Comment: that's why the title of my question says [how to] "make sshd override login shell". updated the question-body to reflect that...

Comment: @umläute you should understand that SSH can't override the login shell. The login shell is what it is, `ForceCommand` doesn't change that. Try running a shell script as a `ForceCommand` which prints `$SHELL`.

Comment: @umläute see update.

Comment: the update seems promising; i tried something like that before but failed; i will try again following your suggestion when i'm back at the machine.

Comment: actually that did the trick; i don't know why my prior tests with such a wrapper script failed (esp. since my wrapper was identical to yours :-()

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem: a server must allow scp sftp and rsync for all users but no connection with command line. User database is in ldap and we cannot modify /etc/passwd locally. rssh was therefore not an option.

One solution I have found is by using `ForceCommand` and a shell script.
In /etc/ssh/sshd_config adding these lines:

```
Match user *
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand /usr/local/bin/wrapper-shell user1 user2 user3
```

Where `userX` are special users allowed to log in via ssh.
The wrapper-shell script, which do the actual filtering, is:

```
#!/bin/sh
SSHCMD=`echo "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" | awk '{ print $1 }'`
ME=`id -u -n`
DOIT=Maybe
# Root is always allowed in order to not being locked out
for n in root $*
do
  if [ "$ME" = "$n" ]
  then
    DOIT=YES
    break
  fi
done
if [ "$DOIT" = YES -o "$SSHCMD" = "scp" -o "$SSHCMD" = "rsync" -o "$SSHCMD" = /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server ]
then
    sh -c "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
else
    cat <<EOF 1>&2

This account is restricted and the command is not allowed.

User $ME is locked out.

If you believe this is in error, please contact your system administrator.
EOF
    exit 1
fi
```